# fatal error 'stdio.h' Python 2.7.3 on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: python, mysql, macos, python-2.7

I was told that this question is better suited here at Stack Overflow ( and not ServerFault )

So here it goes:

I have this weird issue on my Mac OS X 10.7.5

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
```

What caused the above error? 
This error has been bugging me and i can't install mysql-python as i'm stuck with this step.

I'm using Python 2.7.3.
Things like Google App Engine ( python ), python script, tornado generally works on my mac. But not mysql-python.

I've install MySQL using the dmg image and have copied the mysql folder to /usr/local/

How do i fix this?

I've also tried running the command: `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/`
and than installing mysql-python by running 
`sudo python setup.py install`.

But received the following:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing MySQL_python.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to MySQL_python.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to MySQL_python.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'MySQL_python.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
gcc-4.2 not found, using clang instead
building '_mysql' extension
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,4,'rc',5) -D__version__=1.2.4c1 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
In file included from _mysql.c:29:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

What other possible ways can i fix it?

thanks!

Best Regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out.

Just need to install the command line tools found in Xcode and the problems will be solved.

Cheers.

Comment: do you mean that there are specific tools within Xcode, or to simply install Xcode as it is?

Comment: oh apologies, missed your comment. in Xcode, you will find this thing called command line tools. Install that and it will be fine. hope this helps!